# Absolute continuity in terms of sequences

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mu_n$, $\sigma_n$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ be probability measures on compact subset $X$ of $\mathbb C$.

If $\mu_n \to \mu$ and $\sigma_n \to \sigma$ as $n \to \infty$ in the weak* topology then how can we characterize absolute continuity of $\mu$ with respect to $\sigma$ in terms of $\mu_n$ and $\sigma_n$?

Comment: To be honest I do not think that there is a relation. For example, think about the sequences of probability measure on the compact set $[0,1] \subset\mathbb R \subset \mathbb C$, $\mu_n (A) = \int_A \mathbb{d}x$ and $\sigma_n = n\int \chi_{[0,1/n]} \text{d}x$, $\mu_n \to \int_{(\cdot)} \text{d}x$ and $\sigma_n\to \delta_{0}$, aparently there is no relation between the dirac measure and the lebesgue measure.

Comment: @MatheusManzatto Yes, there is no relation between lebesgue and dirac measure but if there is ralation between $\mu$ and $\sigma$ then we can hope for some relation between $\mu_n$ and $\sigma_n$.

Comment: I don't think such a characterization exists.

Comment: @MayureshL if we define $μ_n(x)=∫_{(⋅)}\text{d}x$ and $\nu_n=\frac{1}{n+1}∑_{i=0}^{n} δ_{i/n}$. I think that $μ_n→∫_{(⋅)}\text{d}x$ and $\nu_n→∫(⋅)\text{d}x$, but $\mu_n$ and $\nu_n$ have no relation.